# Change styles for all numbers in string Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers, styles

How to change styles for all numbers in strings (from strings.xml) to (small) and (subscript) and (color.blue)? and where put that in recyclerView adapter (all strings in Array)?

Like footer numbers:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply styles directly to String resources. Style is applied to views (TextView for example) containing the resource string.

You have to create a styles.xml in the values directory, then create a style you can apply to specific views:

```
    <style name="TextViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
```

Here you can define all the attributes you want to modify.

Then in the TextView you want to style:

```
        <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .../>
```

All the attributes defined in the style will be automatically applied.
Do this for every view you want to style

If you want to apply the style to the item in your recyclerview adapter you have to modify the views in item.xml (or whatever you have named the layout to inflate) in order for it to include the style you created.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but my question is: How to make numbers in text string taken special style, not all string.

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually do that...
maybe with a binding adapter? (again, not sure about that tho) 
Can you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Edit my Question, see it...